# Multiple Roles with single Large Application vs Multiple Application REST API same database

Tags: rest

Let say we are build an ecommerce application for web and mobile using REST API with Admin, Merchants and customers roles using Laravel/Lumen.

Is it a good best practice to have separated application for each roles with single database?

Answer (score -1):

One application will usually suffice. It is usually best practice to have a single API (or a single set of microservices) where endpoints enforce your security policies for each role - rather than separate services for each role. This is more maintainable because these services typically share a lot of logic.

On the front end, it may be a different story. You might want a separate Admin app that has such different functionality that it makes sense to build it separately.

Comment: Does it make the large application hard to maintain. We actually don't know how large it may become in future.

Comment: It's almost certainly going to be harder to maintain three applications. Just make sure you manage role based access in a clear and consistent way.